# Can't connect to Database to execute Identity functions

Tags: authentication, migration, asp.net-mvc-5, localdb

I've created a new application with ASP.NET MVC5, using Individual User Accounts for security and Code-First Migrations for the Models/Database modeling. All options are default.

I want to setup custom Users and Roles to it, so i created a Seed using `RoleManager` and `UserManager` just to populate the Database. It works fine, create 3 Users, 3 Roles and set each User's Role correctly.

I can log in to the application correctly. The problem is that i can't execute any Identity method using the 
**User**, which is the logged User, the only things that i can get is the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` value, and the `User.Identity.Name`, which are correct. Every other method like `Roles.GetRolesForUser("John")`, or `User.IsInRole("Student")`, always generates this exception:

> ProviderException : The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

So okay, as in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874279/the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled), i managed to insert the the `<roleManager enabled="true" />` in the Web.config, and now it takes a **really long time to respond**, and generates Exceptions like:

Referring to:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole("Student")
```

Generates:

```
HttpException
```

Referring to:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)
```

Generates:

```
NullReferenceException
```

Accessing the About page with a User in Student role logged in:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Teacher")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

Generates:

```
SqlException
HttpException
```

It's like i have no connection to the Database at all, which is LocalDB, automatically generated and i could populate in the Seed Method and even make Login to the application.

I could even load data from the AspNetUsers table and show it in the View using the code below:

```cs
using (Models.ApplicationDbContext db = new Models.ApplicationDbContext())
{
    List<Models.ApplicationUser> Users = db.Users.ToList();

    ViewBag.Users = Users;
}

return View();
```

**PLEASE HELP :'(**

---

Here's the Seed code, that works fine, so it can connect to the Database using the Identity engine.

```cs
protected override void Seed(LocalBDAuthTest.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    #region Create Roles Student, Teacher e Administrator

    var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

    // Student
    if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("Student"))
    {
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Student"));
    }

    // Teacher
    if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("Teacher"))
    {
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Teacher"));
    }

    // Administrator
    if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
    {
        RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Create Users for Student, Teacher e Administrator Roles.

    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));


    // Create a Student user and set it's role to Student
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "John"))
    {
        var Student = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "John" };
        var Result = UserManager.Create(Student, "123456");
    }
    if (!UserManager.FindByName("John").Roles.Any())
    {
        UserManager.AddToRole(UserManager.FindByName("John").Id, "Student");
    }


    // Create a Teacher user and set it's role to Teacher
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Arnold"))
    {
        var Teacher = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Arnold" };
        var Result = UserManager.Create(Teacher, "123456");
        UserManager.AddToRole(Teacher.Id, "Teacher");
    }
    if (!UserManager.FindByName("Arnold").Roles.Any())
    {
        UserManager.AddToRole(UserManager.FindByName("Arnold").Id, "Teacher");
    }


    // Create a Administrator user and set it's role to Administrator
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Caroline"))
    {
        var Administrator = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Caroline" };
        var Result = UserManager.Create(Administrator, "123456");
        UserManager.AddToRole(Administrator.Id, "Administrator");
    }
    if (!UserManager.FindByName("Caroline").Roles.Any())
    {
        UserManager.AddToRole(UserManager.FindByName("Caroline").Id, "Administrator");
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is due to having a mix of both ASP.NET Identity and ASP.NET Membership, having done this:

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

You enabled membership `SqlRoleProvider`, which use the role store in the default SQL Express instance in a database in your Web site's \app_dir folder.

If you open your machine.config, you'll find:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
      AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
.
.
.
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" ...
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

Most likely you don't have SQL Express installed, and that's why you are getting timeouts and SQL exceptions.

For ASP.NET Identity DON'T use `System.Web.Security.Roles` (it is part of the ASP.NET Membership) but use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager` instead.

Comment: Damn, you are right! I wiped roleManager form Web.config. Now it leaves only to the Database Connection error. If i put [Authorize(Roles = "rolename")] in some Action, then go the View of that Action, i get long timeouts, and after the long wait, SqlExceptions and HttpExceptions, saying that they can't connect to the Database. How is that possible? I use LocalDB in it's latest version, it's installed, along with SQL Express and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, which should come with the whole package, right?

Comment: Not sure about your exact setup, recheck your web.config connection strings also recheck your code for connection keys being used. its gotta be something you have modified!

Comment: Also note that Authorize attribute is not supposed to hit the database, it operates on `IPrincipal` User in the current `HttpContext` and iterates over the role claims stored in it.

Comment: Ops, i still had <roleManager enabled="true" /> in there somehow... Nailed it! I fixed it and now i can put my hair back in my head again haha, THANKS BRO! <3

Comment: It's a shame i can't just vote up your answer because of my reputation.