# ASP.net aspnetdb.mdf connection string

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, membership-provider, aspnetdb

After configuring the Membership Provider, I noticed that there is no connection string for ASPNETDB.mdf in my web.config.  Shouldn't there be a connection string?  What is the appropriate syntax?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default connection string is defined in machine.config:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```