# Import or export from ASPNETDB.MDF in Web Developer Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, import, visual-web-developer

I have a project in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, which uses a `aspnetdb.mdf` database in the `App_Data` folder. Is there a way to import/export data from other SQL Server or MS Access database tables into/from this `aspnetdb.mdf`?

I tried doing it with SQL Server Management Studio, but I can't connect to aspnetdb.mdf: it doesn't see the folder where `aspnetdb.mdf` is located. I tried setting up permissions to that folder but it still didn't work.

I could however copy aspnetdb.mdf and the log file out of that folder and import data in SQL Server Management Studio. But can't get it back to work with Visual Web Developer.

It seems to be way too complicated for what I'm trying to to. Any help or information about this topic is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: ASPNETDB.MDF is for the user authentication database if you're using that. Here's an answer going in the opposite direction of how to get rid of it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1529332/3585500) and a link to migrate it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I don't know if I described the problem correctly. I am trying to import data into a table in ASPNETDB.MDF database in my website. is it possible? as if I had an inventory of products that I needed to import from other table. I am  having such a hard time for something that should be so easy. Thanks.

Comment: Split text into paragraphs and shorter phrases. Improved on capitalisation.